# Allow computer keypad form be controlled from keyboard

Tags: vb6

I have created a dialer in VB6 to dial a phone number. It has the following buttons: the digits 0-9, backspace, "Call", and "Disconnect". Now I want enter numbers in the form using the keypad part of the keyboard. In the text box, any key can be typed in using the keypad. But I only want the number pad to operate.

For that I checked ASCII values using the KeyPress event - seeing if the pressed key value lies in between 47 and 58. But along with the key values its ASCII values are also getting displayed in the text box.

One more thing - I have one MS Flex Grid on the form along with the dialer. So when the cursor is on the form, or if the mouse is clicked anywhere other than the text box, values don't display in the text box. So how do I always keep focus on the text box?

```
   Dim val As Integer

  Private Sub append(val As Integer)
  Text1.Text = Text1.Text & val
  End Sub   
  Private Sub Backspace_Click()
  With Text1
         'FOCUS TO THE TEXTBOX
         .SetFocus

         'PUT THE CURSOR AT THE END OF THE TEXT
         .SelStart = Len(.Text)

         'SEND THE KEY
         SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")

         'AND THATS IT :D
 End With
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_0_Click()
 val  = 0
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_1_Click()
 val = 1
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_2_Click()
 val = 2
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_3_Click()
 val = 3
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_4_Click()
 val = 4
 append val
 End Sub


 Private Sub key_5_Click()
 val = 5
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_6_Click()
 val = 6
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_7_Click()
 val = 7
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_8_Click()
 val = 8
 append val
 End Sub

 Private Sub key_9_Click()
 val = 9
 append val
 End Sub


 Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
 If (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58) Then
 val = KeyAscii
 append val
 Else
 KeyAscii = 0
```

'    Text1.Text = KeyAscii
     End If
     End Sub

```
'Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
' Text1.SetFocus
'End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't defined `index` anywhere. And in any case, I would recommend not using a variable called `Index` in VB, since it is a common parameter name. The comment "index is the variable append KeyAscii" doesn't make any sense. And the next line mentions a function `Append` that isn't shown here, nor called. Also, I notice you have commented out `Text1.Text = KeyAscii`. Was this for debugging? Because this would definitely displayed the ASCII number in the text box.

Comment: Hey mark, thank you for the reply. Index variable is declared. For some reason i was not allowed to post more than few characters. However i will keep in mind not to use "index" as variable again. Append function might not have pasted here, but it has been called. If i uncomment Text1.Text = keyAscii, it will display '0' in textbox1 as i assigned '0' to KeyAscii in above line. Else no character other than digit 0-9 will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the KeyPreview property on the form to true.
When you have done that, put your code in the KeyPress of the form that was in the KeyPress of the Textbox, and set the text value of the textbox, or better still move the code into a function and set it from there, that way you won't need to duplicate your code if you need it in other places.

Have a look at this and see if it helps it is the [KeyPreview from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235137%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Hi,
Sorry for the delay.  To use the KeyPreview for the form give this a try:

1. Double click on the form in the project to open it
2. In the properties for the form find the KeyPreview Property and set it to true
   [image: Key Press from properties]
3. Double click on the form to bring up the code window
4. Select the keypress event for the form, and add the following code, or something similar.

   ```
   Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
       Text1.Text = Text1.Text & Chr$(NrOnly(KeyAscii))
   End Sub
   ```

Use the function NrOnly that Hqrls has posted as that will allow only numbers which could help you with the validation.  You won't need any code in the Text1_KeyPress, the form will now handle that for you.
Give it a try and let me know if you need any other information and I'll see what I can do.

[EDIT 29/05/2014]

Hi,

I've had a bit of a play around with the code and added some bits in which I think might help.  Have a look at this and see if it make sense.  If you copy it into your code then make sure you back up your original code just in case you need to get back to it.

This is the code if you keep your textbox

```
Option Explicit

Dim val                 As String
Dim m_blnTextHasFocus   As Boolean 'Added this, so it knows wether the the textbox 
                                   'has  the focus or not
                                   'it is so the sendkeys doesn't get stuck in a 
                                   'loop with the key presses

Private Sub append(strIn As String)
    'Changed the parameter from an int to a string, so we can use it in the key press events
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text & strIn
End Sub

Private Sub Backspace_Click()
    'Moved the code into it's own sub
    DeleteAChar
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    'Handle a key press if the textbox doesn't have the focus but ignore the keypress if it does

    If Not m_blnTextHasFocus Then
        If IsNumeric(Chr$(KeyAscii)) Then
            append Chr$(KeyAscii)

        ElseIf KeyAscii = vbKeyBack Then
            DeleteAChar
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub key_0_Click()
    val = "0"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_1_Click()
    val = "1"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_2_Click()
    val = "2"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_3_Click()
    val = "3"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_4_Click()
    val = "4"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_5_Click()
    val = "5"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_6_Click()
    val = "6"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_7_Click()
    val = "7"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_8_Click()
    val = "8"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub key_9_Click()
    val = "9"
    append val
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
    m_blnTextHasFocus = True
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    'Check the keyascii value and ignore it if it isn't numeric or backspace
    If Not IsNumeric(Chr$(KeyAscii)) And KeyAscii <> vbKeyBack Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DeleteAChar()
    With Text1
        'FOCUS TO THE TEXTBOX
        .SetFocus

        'PUT THE CURSOR AT THE END OF THE TEXT
        .SelStart = Len(.Text)

        'SEND THE KEY
        SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")

        'AND THATS IT :D
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
    m_blnTextHasFocus = False
End Sub
```

If you don't need to keep the textbox then you could replace it with a label and have a try with that.  It would remove the need to keep track of if the textbox has got the focus or not.  Have a go with this and see if it helps any.  The only other thing is to make sure KeyPreview is turned on for the form or the keypress code will only work for the form if it has the focus.

Comment: Thanks Lardy, I am totally new to VB6, so it's getting hard to extract what you actually want to say. Tell me how to post whole code here so that you will get to know what I am actually doing.

Comment: Hi, sorry just reread what you have put above.  I think if you click edit on your original post you should be able to put the code in there.  Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Hi lardy, Thanks for your code. However it's not working. It's accepting other characters on keyboard apart from digits. Moreover if command button is pressed then none of the keyboard button is accepted until and unless mouse click is there on text box again. And focusing issue is still there. If click is anywhere else on the form,  no values get's displayed in Text box.

Comment: Hi there.  Is the code that you have posted the code that isn't working with the key press?  If it is then it's because the keypress event you are trapping is for the textbox so you will need to have focus on the textbox for it to fire.  If you change the Private sub Text1_Keypress to be Private sub Form_Keypress then that might help, but you will also need to set the Keypreview property for the form to be true aswell.  Leave it with me.

Comment: Hi, I tried with Form1_Keypress too, but not working. Text box displays all the values entered from the keyboard. I am not finding any solution for it.

Comment: Is that when you have focus on the textbox that you get all the keyboard characters?  Just out of interest, are you using the textbox just to display the number you have typed or do you need to be able to edit it as well?  There may be another option for the textbox I need to have a look and let you know.

Comment: Hey lardy, sorry for the late reply. Anyways thanks a lot for the reply and code. It's really working. No focusing issue, no other characters from the keyboard only digits, backspace and command buttons all are working fine. Thanks a lot lardy. I have written one more code for serial communication with GSM modem. Its working fine. Data string i get when GSM modem receives a call is

Answer (score 0):

Is the textbox the only control you want to have the focus ?

In that case you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Text1_LostFocus()
  Text1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

If there are any other controls you want to be able to have the focus as well, then you can use Text1.SetFocus in the _GotFocus() event of the controls which you do not want to have the focus

Another possible solution would be to use the _KeyPress() event of the other controls as well, and convert your current Text1_KeyPress() event to a general function which can be called by the _KeyPress() event of the other controls .. make sure though that you send the output of this general function to the correct textbox

If you post the relevant parts of your code we might be able to give a more specific answer

**[EDIT]**

for the answer to your original question, go with the answer of lardymonkey using keypreview on the form

an example function for allowed only numeric keys and the backspace:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  KeyAscii = NrOnly(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Function NrOnly(intAscii As Integer) As Integer
  Dim intReturn As Integer
  intReturn = intAscii
  Select Case intAscii
    Case vbKeyBack
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
    Case Else
      intReturn = 0
  End Select
  NrOnly = intReturn
End Function
```

Comment: 'Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If (KeyAscii > 47 And KeyAscii < 58) Then
    index = KeyAscii 'index is the variable
    append KeyAscii  'append is the function to add values to  
    Else             'display on text box 
    KeyAscii = 0
    'Text1.Text = KeyAscii
    End If
    
End Sub'  It's not letting me post the whole code. It's not letting me answer the question.

Comment: the easiest solution would to make sure that your textbox always has the focus .. which you can do with the code i posted in my answer .. is that possible on your form, or do other controls also need the focus?

Comment: Thanx Hrqls. Yes I have another control functions too on the form. As i have mentioned command buttons are there. So when include the code you posted, all the command buttons get's deactivated. Focus remains on Textbox, but it doesn't let enter the keys through command button, only key pad is active. There are other issues in this code too. Code for backspace doesn't work with this logic, More over with digit entered through keyboard on laptop, it displays Ascii value along with key. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: you are right, i expected the _Click() event to fire first before it would return the focus to the textbox, but appearently it doesnt .. the better solution would be what lardymonkey posted

Comment: the other issue, with the backspace not working, and with the ascii value being displayed is something else .. for the backspace you need to allow ascii value 8 (vbKeyBack) .. i will update my answer with some example code

Comment: Ok Hrqls, please tell me how to post code here so that you will get to know about my code.

Comment: edit your first post (not any of the comments) and post your code in there ... when each line of your code starts with at least 4 spaces then it will be converted into a code block ... if it is a question about something else, then you might also create a new post with just that question (and the relevant code)

Comment: Hi Hrqls,none of the solutions provided are working. I don't know why.

Comment: hi @user3678480, what did you try? could you post the relevant code?

Comment: hi hrqls, code posted by lardy is working perfectly fine. That issue is solved.Now I am struggling with the serial communication with GSM module.

Comment: Ah ok. Please accept his answer as the solution then so that everyone knows that it has solved the problem you posted. (You can also upvote his answer if you like :)) .... post your problem about the communication with the gsm module as a new question please

Comment: Hi Hrqls, how to upvote his answer and mark the thread as solved. I searched the option for same but couldn't get it.

Comment: To the left of the answer is the number 1 with an arrow pointing up and an arrow pointing down ... click on the arrow pointing up to upvote, and there should also be a check mark to mark that answer as the solution .. when you hold your mouse over the object but dont click yet, it will show you some info about the object